# Rate limit with golang.org/x/time/rate api request

Tags: go, limit, rate

I already created a function for limiting to 50 requests for API logins in one day.

var limit = 50

```
package middleware

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/time/rate"
)

// Create a custom request struct which holds the rate limiter for each
// visitor and the last time that the request was seen.
type request struct {
    limiter  *rate.Limiter
    lastSeen time.Time
}

// Change the the map to hold values of the type request.
// defaultTime using 3 minutes
var requests = make(map[string]*request)
var mu sync.Mutex

func getRequest(ip string, limit int) *rate.Limiter {
    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()

    v, exists := requests[ip]
    if !exists {
        limiter := rate.NewLimiter(1, limit)
        requests[ip] = &request{limiter, time.Now()}
        return limiter
    }
    // Update the last seen time for the visitor.
    v.lastSeen = time.Now()
    return v.limiter
}

func throttle(next http.Handler, limit int) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ip, _, err := net.SplitHostPort(r.RemoteAddr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err.Error())
            http.Error(w, "Internal Server Error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        limiter := getRequest(ip, limit)
        fmt.Println(limiter.Allow())
        if limiter.Allow() == false {
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusTooManyRequests), http.StatusTooManyRequests)
            return
        }
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Is it correct?

Because when I try it, it still passes. The function limit is not working.

I doubt with NewLimiter()

```
 limiter := rate.NewLimiter(1, limit)
```

Does it mean one user only can request login 50 requests per day? (I already read the docs, but I do not understand.)

Answer (score 3):

From the [rate docs](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/time/rate#NewLimiter):

```
func NewLimiter(r Limit, b int) *Limiter
```

> NewLimiter returns a new Limiter that allows events up to rate r and
>   permits bursts of at most b tokens.

---

So the first parameter is the rate-limit, not the second. Burst is the number of requests you want to allow that occur *faster* than the rate-limit - typically one uses a value of `1` to disallow bursting, anything higher will let this number of requests in before the regular rate-limit kicks in. Anyway...

To create the `rate.Limit` for your needs, you can use the helper function `rate.Every()`:

```
rt := rate.Every(24*time.Hour / 50)

limiter := rate.NewLimiter(rt, 1)
```

Comment: i already test with

rt := rate.Every(5*time.Minute / 5)

limiter := rate.NewLimiter(rt, 1)

means 5req/5 minute 
so if i request 6 times under 5 minute will give me error (to many request) ??
but when i test its not should be

Comment: are you sure your test was valid? You are storing each limiter under an `ip` key - are you sure that key is the same each time? Maybe remove the individual limiters first - and use a single one - to prove the limiter is working first - before switching to individual `ip` limiters.

Comment: @agnyreza Here is a working example of rate-limiter given an acceptable rate of requests; then an exceeded level - and then switching back: https://play.golang.org/p/dWH6ZQY8tD1

Comment: @colm.anseo I modified your code code a little bit, just using 0.0 as Limit.. and something weird occurs: all the call to Allow() returns true.. Using limit 0.0 should not allow any request.. that right?
https://play.golang.org/p/hVPT-KUPMAN

Comment: @colm.anseo Sorry this one: https://play.golang.org/p/_vqaCPq58SZ
Because the first one uses Every (and Every return Inf in case of 0)

Answer (score 1):

`NewLimited(1, 50)` means 1 request/second with a burst of up to 50 requests. It's a token bucket, which means that there are 50 tokens, each accepted API call uses up one token, and the tokens are regenerated at the given rate, up to `burst`. Your code is creating a limiter per IP address, so that's a limit per IP address (which I guess you are approximating as one IP address is one user).

If you're running on a single persistent server, and the server and code never restarts, then you may be able to get something like 50 requests/day per user by specifying a rate of `50 / (3600*24)` and a burst of 50. (Note: `3600*24` is the number of seconds in a day). But the rate limiting package you're using is not designed for such coarse rate-limiting (on the order of requests per day) -- it's designed to prevent server overload under heavy traffic in the short term (on the order of requests per second).

You probably want a rate-limiter that works with a database or similar (perhaps using a token bucket scheme, since that can be implemented efficiently). Probably there's a package somewhere for that, but I don't know of one of the top of my head.